# why we dont pass pointer arguments in strstr in main function

Tags: strstr

```
char *strstr(char *string2, char string*1)
```

In `strstr` function the arguments are pointer strings but when we pass arguments from main.. Why do we use only strings but not their address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
   char s1 [] = "My House is small";
   char s2 [] = "My Car is green";

   printf ("Returned String 1: %s\n", strstr (s1, "House"));
   printf ("Returned String 2: %s\n", strstr (s2, "Car"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s1 and s2 are (or can be used as) pointers. They both point to the first character of the string.

Here is the text from c standard

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

I should mention that you could define a string with.

```
char* s1 = "My House is small";
```

But this would not be the same as

```
char s1 [] = "My House is small";
```

Because `char* s1` would be defined in some read-only memory containing the string-literal and `char s1 []` would be defined as a static array on the stack.